# How to get the value of a property from a function which returns an object?

Tags: c#, function, oop, object

I have this function which returns an object:

```
 private object function1()
 {
   return new
   {
     string1 = "a",
     string2 = "b"
   }
 }
```

I want to store 'string1' into a variable. How will I achieve this? Here's what I tried but it does not solve the problem:

```
var a = function1().string1;
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be returning anonymous types, make a proper class and return that instead. Otherwise you have to resort to reflection or dynamic types which is just hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1 - Do it properly

<sub>In other words, don't use the other methods unless you *really* have to</sub>

You really shouldn't be returning anonymous types, the correct way to do this is make a proper class and return that instead. Otherwise you have to resort to reflection or dynamic types which is just hacky:

Class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String1 { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
private Foo Function1()
{
    return new Foo
    {
        String1 = "a",
        String2 = "b"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = Function1().String1; // Though it's worth checking for a null return in production code
```

## Option 2 - Use reflection

<sub>In other words, please don't do this</sub>

Using your code above, you can use reflection to get the property and call it manually, for example:

```
var result = function1();

var property = result.GetType().GetProperty("string1");
var a = (string)property.GetValue(result);
```

## Option 3 - Use dynamic typing

<sub>In other words, pretty please with sugar on top, don't do this!</sub>

Cast the return to dynamic and you can call any method/property you like, but this is not type safe and will throw a runtime exception if you call a non-existent method.

```
var result = (dynamic)function1();
var a = (string)result.string1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to use a proper class definition instead of returning an anonymous type

```
class MyClass {
    string string1 {get;set;}
    string string2 {get;set;}
}


private MyClass function1() {
    return new MyClass {
       string1 = "a", string2 = "b"
    };
}


Console.WriteLine(function1().string1);
```

If you really want to use anonymous types you will have to use reflection. Be aware, there is no errorhandling in the code below. You will have to check, wheter the property exists, and has the correct type!

```
public class Program
{
    public static object f1() {
        return new {string1 = "a", string2 = "b"};
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = f1();
        var p = x.GetType().GetProperty("string1");
        string s = (string)p.GetValue(x);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class to do it in stead of return a new object:

```
public class TestClass
{
public string str1{set;get;}
public string str2{set;get;}
}
```

Example:

```
private TestClass function1()
 {
   return new TestClass()
   {
     str1 = "a",
     str2 = "b"
   }
 }
```

Usage:

```
var a = function1().str1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the *proper* way of doing it is creating a class to return the result.

However, as of C# 7 there is another option called *tuple deconstruction* (note: you need at least a C# 7 compiler like the one in Visual Studio 2017 for this to work):

```
private (string, string) Function1()
{
  return ("a", "b");
}

// In your calling method:
(string left, string right) = Function1();
System.Console.WriteLine($"left = {left}, right = {right}.");
```

Comment: How is this any different from returning a class?

Comment: @DavidG in that you are not returning a class but a `Tuple`.

Comment: The sentiment behind "returning a class" isn't that it's a class, it's that it's a concrete object of some sort. Could have been a struct for example. So whether it's a class, struct or tuple, it's all the same really.

Comment: I understand. What I'm trying to do is provide an alternative to the existing answers ("return an instance of a class specifically defined for this purpose") while avoiding the downsides of the other options such as returning an anonymous class, using reflection and `dynamic`.